# How to extract .tar file in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, zip, gzip, tar

I downloaded a file from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WfrELBlEoq5WO7gKUv-MLTQ8QHY-2wiX/view and it got downloaded as **cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.zip**.

Then I extracted the file using 
`unzip cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.zip`
 Now a new file named **cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.tar** is created

When I try to extract filename.tar from terminal using the command

```
tar -xvf filename.tar
```

I get the error :

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

when I check the file type using command :

```
file filename.tar
```

I get the result as :

```
filename.tar : 8086 relocatable (Microsoft)
```

**Why does the unzip command create a file with extension .tar ?**

Comment: Well the first thing you do wrong is to treat a zip file as if it were a tar file (these are two distinct file formats). Why do you rename `file_name.zip` to `filename.tar` ? Have you tried `unzip file_name.zip` ?

Comment: Had a deeper look, file `cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.zip` contains `cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.tar` which as far as I can see is just a misnamed `cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth`. By "neutralizing" the filenames in your question that was made a lot harder to understand...

Comment: @fvu .....Thank for clearing my doubt. You are right . When I remove .tar , Iit is in correct format. Actually when I unzip cub_epoch_100_glo_step_20200.pth.zip the new file was created with .tar extension. That made me misunderstand the fact. Why does the unzip command create the file with extension .tar ?

Comment: See previous comment, the zip file actually contains a file with the erroneous extension tar,

Answer (score 0):

Your file might be of ['.obj' format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_Object_Module_Format).

```
file filename.tar
```

if it is a tar file it will output:

filename.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Comment: Thanks for replying .As I mentioned the outpput of file filename.tar is        
 "filename.tar : 8086 relocatable (Microsoft)".